# Can't logout in mobile browser using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I am working on a SaaS web app and I have login and logout in the app using JWT (JSON WEB TOKEN).

All the things are working fine in desktop browser like Chrome and Firefox but as I open my web app in mobile browser. I am able to login but when I click on logout I am not able to logout.

here is my code for generating JWT

```
const generateToken = (req, res, users) => {
  var token = jwt.sign(
    {
      data: {
        email: users[0].email,
        password: users[0].password,
        userID: users[0].userId
      }
    },
    process.env.JWT_SECRET
  );

  res.cookie('TOKEN-NAME', token, {
    domain: req.hostname,
    maxAge: 2592000000, // 30 days : (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30)
    httpOnly: true
  });
};
```

and this is code for logout

```
router.get('/logout', function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.cookies['ONTRO-BIZ-TOKEN'])
    res.status(400).send('Please login first');
  else {
    res.clearCookie('ONTRO-BIZ-TOKEN');
    res.sendStatus(200).redirect('/login');
  }
});
```

and this is my Frontend code having the logout code

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      isLoggedIn: Cookies.get('isLoggedIn')
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    if (this.state.isLoggedIn) {
      Account.get().then(({data}) => {
        this.setState({ user: data })
        window.me = data
      }).catch(err => handleErrors(this, err))
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isLoggedIn) {
      return <LoginModal setLoggedIn={(data) => {
        Cookies.set('isLoggedIn', true);
        this.setState({ user: data, isLoggedIn: true });
        window.me = data;
      }}/>
    }
    if (!this.state.user) {
      return <Loading/>
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <ShortcutHandler>
            <TopBar user={this.state.user}/>
            <div className="ContentPane d-flex">
              <SideBar />
              <div className="Content">
                <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
                <Route path="/venues" component={Venues} />
                <Route path="/trainers" component={TrainersList} />
                <Route path="/classes" component={Coaching} />
                <Route path="/plans" component={Coaching} />
                <Route path="/customers/:id(\d+)?" component={PlayersList} />
                <Route path="/enrollments/:id(\d+)?" component={Subscriptions} />
                <Route path="/invoices/:id(\d+)?" component={Invoices} />
                <Route path="/payments/:id(\d+)?" component={PaymentsList} />
                <Route path="/analytics" component={ComingSoon} />
                <Route path="/settings" component={Settings} />
                <Route path="/logout" component={logout.bind(this)} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </ShortcutHandler>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

export const logout = () => {
  Cookies.remove('isLoggedIn');
  window.me = undefined;
  window.currentOrg = undefined;
  window.location.pathname = '/';
  return null;
}
```

Comment: What is your mobile, browser? Did you debug your mobile version on your computer?

Comment: I am having Samsung J7 mobile but it is not working on any mobile and can you please tell me how to debug my mobile version on computer

Comment: You need a USB cable to connect your device on your computer https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: Hey thanks for your help and I have debugged it my mobile and I have noticed one thing that when i am clicking on the logout button in the mobile mode the logout api is not been called

Comment: and when I make the website back to normal desktop mode then when i click on the logout button then the api is called

Comment: Hey when I am testing my web app in toggle device toolbar mode  in chrome it is not working else it is working

Comment: Did you check that your button is actually clicked in mobile? Seems like a stupid question but it can happens that some element is overlapping the button and it is not clicked...